# How to set hwclock to UTC?

Tags: linux, time, utc

The times on my arch linux workstation got messed up, so I set the system time with `date` and then the hardware time with

```
sudo hwclock --systohc --utc
```

Now the `hwclock` gives:

```
Do 04 Apr 2013 14:12:48 CEST  -0.641471 seconds
```

but I want it to use UTC, which would be 12:12:48! How do I achieve this?

*edit:*

some additional weirdness:

```
$ hwclock --utc
Do 04 Apr 2013 14:20:56 CEST  -0.188214 seconds
$ hwclock --localtime
Do 04 Apr 2013 12:21:01 CEST  -0.438205 seconds
$ date -u
Do 4. Apr 12:21:11 UTC 2013
$ date
Do 4. Apr 14:21:16 CEST 2013
```

utc and localtime seems to be confused by hwclock...

Comment: `hwclock` shows the local time, even if the hardware clock is on UTC. To find out what's really going on, use `timedatectl` — "RTC time" is your hardware clock. Use `ntpd -qg` and `hwclock -w` to get the hardware clock set right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, in Linux you can use `hwclock --systohc`, and pay your attention to its manual saying that «…

> The time shown is always in local time, even if you keep your Hardware Clock in Coordinated Universal Time.  See the --utc option.  Showing the  Hardware Clock time is the default when no function is specified.

…»

And, BTW, my `man hwclock` also reveals option `--debug` which would really help you in your search of the truth.

Comment: ahrghhh! so `hwclock --localtime` shows the local time assuming that the hardware clock is using localtime, which results in something that appears wrong at firts sight!!! Fair enough...

Comment: @steffen, see update regarding `--debug` also…

Comment: yep, that makes it clear... it is confusing, though. With `date` the option changes what is to be desplayed, while with `hwclock` the option changes the assumption in order to calculate the displayed time.

Answer (score 0):

hwclock and timedatectl shous different info about cmos (hardware_clock)

ubuntu 20.04 dell laptop

My hardware clock show up less time than utc and the observation is with

Recife-PE - London-GB (greenwich)

Thanks

No idea what is occurring,
but with timedatectl setup to localrtc 1 appears to gos to normal back

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/519558)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hwclock --set --date "2022-05-03 00:23:00" && sudo hwclock --localtime
```

after above command as root, run `timedatectl`:

```
timedatectl (warning disappears relative to rtc)
```

no reboot necessary.